# How to place Bootstrap modal window on top of the source element instead of the top of the whole page?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

The default modal window is placed at top of the page, like the below one:
[image]

How to achieve the below effect, to place the modal window on top of the opening element:
[image]

Comment: I feel like you might want to use a bootstrap Popover instead https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/

Comment: Bootstrap modals are made with position: fixed, so in theory you could put them in another fixed container to control the position but they just aren't designed for it